# How to set filter for FileSystemWatcher for multiple file types?

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

Everywhere I find these two lines of code used to set filter for file system watcher in samples provided..

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
//or
watcher.Filter = "*.*";
```

But I want my watcher to monitor more file types, but not all. How can I achieve this:

```
//watcher.Filter = "*.txt" | "*.doc" | "*.docx" | "*.xls" | "*.xlsx";
```

I tried these:

```
 watcher.Filter = "*.txt|*.doc|*.docx|*.xls|*.xlsx"; 
 // and
 watcher.Filter = "*.txt;*.doc;*.docx;*.xls;*.xlsx*";
```

Both did not work. This is just basics but I miss it. Thanks..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Since .Net Core 3.x and .Net 5 Preview you can simply add multiple filters to the [`Filters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filters?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_FileSystemWatcher_Filters) collection.

```
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = "/your/path";
watcher.Filters.Add("*.yml");
watcher.Filters.Add("*.yaml");
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Alternatively if you like object initializers,

```
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher
    {
        Path = "/your/path",
        Filters = {"*.yml", "*.yaml"},
        NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName,
        EnableRaisingEvents = true,
    };
```

Comment: This was very helpful for me (.NET 5.0) but I'd like to point out that you can't use `Filters` directly during the initialization since it's read only. You have use `Filters.Add` instead.

Comment: @root you can use it directly as I've specified here because the object initializer calls `Add` under the hood

Comment: I tried it and got a "read only" error, hence my previous comment.
In the definition you can see that there's no setter: `FileSystemWatcher.Filters { get; }`

Answer (score 92):

You can't do that. The `Filter` property only supports one filter at a time. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter.aspx):

> Use of multiple filters such as `*.txt|*.doc` is not supported.

You need to create a `FileSystemWatcher` for each file type. You can then bind them all to the same set of `FileSystemEventHandler`:

```
string[] filters = { "*.txt", "*.doc", "*.docx", "*.xls", "*.xlsx" };
List<FileSystemWatcher> watchers = new List<FileSystemWatcher>();

foreach(string f in filters)
{
    FileSystemWatcher w = new FileSystemWatcher();
    w.Filter = f;
    w.Changed += MyChangedHandler;
    watchers.Add(w);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for that. I need not even wait for other answers since Microsoft tells on face that its not possible! :x :)

Comment: According to pbls624's answer this is less inefficient than registering for `*.*` and do the filtering manually.

Comment: All I have to say is....wow.  I'm in awe.  Both because of the brilliance behind this code and the fault of the guys at Microsoft that would require something like this!  @AndersAbel, good job!

Comment: @JackMiller I think you meant to say that this is less efficient, not less inefficient

Answer (score 60):

There is a workaround.

The idea is to watch for all extensions and then in the OnChange event, filter out to desired extensions:

```
FileSystemWatcher objWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(); 
objWatcher.Filter = ""; // This matches all filenames
objWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged); 

private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    // get the file's extension 
    string strFileExt = getFileExt(e.FullPath); 

    // filter file types 
    if (Regex.IsMatch(strFileExt, @"\.txt)|\.doc", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("watched file type changed."); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Nice workaround. Do you know if this will affect performance?

Comment: @Anders Abel: Your guess is as good as mine! If the watched folder gets lot of file changes,and if most of those changes are for _unwatched_ file types, then you're incurring a penalty. Otherwise, it shouldn't be that much of an overhead. At the end, there is nothing else you can do, right? (unless going to Win32 API)

Comment: Haha. Mrchief, a cool workaround. I'm not sure if I would go for that. @Anders Abel has given another workaround. Now I'm confused which to mark as answer.. :)

Comment: I thought of that too :). Irrespective of what you mark as answer, can you please do some profiling and see which one is optimum performance wise (memory/cpu/disk i/o mainly)? Curious to know... I hate `FileSystemWatchers`, but there's no alternative :(

Comment: @Anders Abel: Are you sure your method would give better performance?

Comment: @Mrchief I'm too naive to do all that. I never tried profiling :(

Comment: @nawfal: No, I'm not sure - to be sure requires doing some profiling. I'd guess that my method is better if there are few types to be watched and lots of files not matching the pattern. MrChief's method works best in the opposite case: Most files match and there are many patterns. For code readability I prefer mine - it gives cleaner event handlers.

Comment: Though I'll be using Mrchief's answer in my code for its simplicity, I'm going to mark @Anders Abel's as answer since he came up with the answer first and with a cleaner method. Thanks to all! :)

Comment: Please note that setting up a watcher takes quite some resources as well. You will need to set the buffer-size of the watchers to a number above the default if you expect a lot of files (else performance will not be an issue anyway) and so you will allocate quite a lot of memory (opposite to CPU in the solution of Mrchief)

Comment: After [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34041620/661933) from pbls624 I am accepting this as answer.

Comment: Much easier than that RegEx is to just look for `if (strFileExt.ToLower().EndsWith(".txt") || strFileExt.ToLower().EndsWith(".doc")) { ... }`

Comment: Sure, for a few that may work. But if you want to watch a lot of extensions, those if statements can quickly grow out of hand.

Answer (score 32):

A quick look in the reflector shows that the filtering is done in .Net code after the windows api has reported the file system change.

I'd therefore suggest that the approach of registering multiple watchers is inefficient as you're putting more load on the API causing multiple callbacks and only one of the filters will match. Much better to just register a single watcher and filter the results yourself.

Comment: @vape Personally I think this answer adds very valuable info to the question. I can attest to his finding seeing source code.

Answer (score 24):

To expand on Mrchief's and jdhurst's solution:

```
private string[] extensions = { ".css", ".less", ".cshtml", ".js" };
private void WatcherOnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs fileSystemEventArgs)
{
    var ext = (Path.GetExtension(fileSystemEventArgs.FullPath) ?? string.Empty).ToLower();

    if (extensions.Any(ext.Equals))
    {
        // Do your magic here
    }
}
```

This eliminates the regex checker (which in my mind is too much overhead), and utilizes Linq to our advantage.  :)

*Edited - Added null check to avoid possible NullReferenceException.*

Comment: Why not use just "extensions.Contains(ext)" ? Simpler. Or even better, "extensions.Contains(ext, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)"

Answer (score 3):

You could also filter by using [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) by comparing to the string of the extension you're looking for.

For example the handler for a file changed event could look like:

```
void File_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);

    if (f.Extension.Equals(".jpg") || f.Extension.Equals(".png"))
    {
       //Logic to do whatever it is you're trying to do goes here               
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what Mrchief's answer is essentially.