# how can you monitor multiple shared files in an application that uses FileSystemWatcher to monitor multiple folders

Tags: c#

So there is a server and a LAN with ALL files shared. The Database is on the server, and contains information about the files that are physically stored in a specific Shared Folder (let's say E:\Shared).

The `Filter` property of FileSystemWatcher allows watching All files in a specific folder: `*.*` or just one type of file, ex.: `*.txt`, or only one, by name: `code.txt`.

I wonder if I can give multiple files (names from the Database) as arguments (like `aaa.txt; bbb.txt; ccc.txt`) in a `textbox` from a `Form`, with the use of the `String.Split()` command
to separate the strings then process them, or another way.

Comment: You may see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965184/how-to-set-filter-for-filesystemwatcher-for-different-file-types). Can give some insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter.aspx):

*To watch changes in all files, set the Filter property to an empty string (""). To watch a specific file, set the Filter property to the file name. For example, to watch for changes in the file MyDoc.txt, set the Filter property to "MyDoc.txt". You can also watch for changes in a certain type of file. For example, to watch for changes in any text files, set the Filter property to "*.txt". **Use of multiple filters such as "*.txt|*.doc" is not supported.***

Having said that, as an aside I would also recommend from personal experience that you not use FileSystemWatcher at all as it is unreliable, and either get a 3rd party library that provides a more reliable alternative or write your own service to fulfill your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If the files don't conform to any particular pattern, I would watch all files and check the database when an `FileSystemWatcher` event occurs to see if we really care about that file.