# FileSystemWatcher: multiple type

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I want to send a file which has been found when the System Watcher has discoverd a created file ending with **"*.txt", "*.doc" or "*.docx"***. My Problem is that the System Watcher discover just files ending with ".txt".

Here is my Code:

```
private String Attachmenttosend
{
    get { return attachmentfile; }
    set { attachmentfile = value; }
}

private void NewFileSystemWatcher()
{
    String filter = "*.txt,*.doc,*.docx";   
    string[] FileExtension = filter.Split(',');  
    for (int i = 0; i < FileExtension.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(folder); // on its own Thread
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(NewEMail); 
        attachmenttosend.Add(Attachmenttosend); 
        watcher.Filter = FileExtension[i];
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watchlist.Add(watcher);
    }
    Send(Attachmenttosend); 
}

private void NewEMail(Object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    while (Locked(e.FullPath)) // check if the file is used
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
    Attachmenttosend = e.FullPath; // store the filename 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965184/how-to-set-filter-for-filesystemwatcher-for-multiple-file-types

Comment: you want to catch every modification of any file in a specific directory?

Comment: if a file (or more) was created (endig with .txt, .doc or .docx) then should the systemwatcher discover that/those file(s) and give me the name of the file back. It works only for *.txt. Like in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965184/how-to-set-filter-for-filesystemwatcher-for-multiple-file-types I created for every file extension a FileSystemWatcher object.

Comment: try to comment out the attachment lines and the while loop in new mail and check if it returns the event by printing it in NewEMail.

Comment: what does this line does "attachmenttosend.Add(Attachmenttosend);"

Comment: attachmenttosend is a List<String> : It does add the filename that the system watcher has found when a file was created with one of this extensions "*.txt,*.doc or*.docx"

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you,just create a console app on the fly and paste this in and try it out:

```
        private static string[] filters = new string[] { ".txt", ".doc", ".docx" };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = @"C:\...\...\...";//your directory here
            /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
               the renaming of files or directories. */
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
               | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            //dont set this
            //watcher.Filter = "*.txt";

            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {          
            if(filters.Contains(Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
                //Attachmenttosend = e.FullPath;
            }
        }

        private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (filters.Contains(Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath)))
            Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
        }
```

Also as Kunal pointed out

> attachmenttosend.Add(Attachmenttosend);

I guess from the uppercase and lower case that you are trying to add to the backing field of the property its own property,dont,also...you dont add to a string only += (concat). 
Unless  attachmenttosend is a for example a list of strings.

Comment: attachmenttosend is a List<String> : It does add the filename that the system watcher has found when a file was created with one of this extensions ".txt,.doc or*.docx"