# FileSystemWatcher specific files with filename keywords filter

Tags: c#, .net, regex, filesystemwatcher

I am using below code for watching files on local system using FileSystemWatcher class. What I would like to do is watch only those filename which I specify in keywords (could be a comma separated string or txt file).
Please guide me in the right direction.

```
   FileSystemWatcher objWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(); 
   objWatcher.Filter = "*.*"; 
   objWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged); 

   private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) 
   { 
     string strFileExt = getFileExt(e.FullPath); 
   }
```

***Thanks & Regards***

Comment: See if _Filter_ supports regex pattern.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965184/how-to-set-filter-for-filesystemwatcher-for-multiple-file-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the FileSystemWatcher doesn't support that, you can get that functionality by filtering the filename after the event is raised.  You wont be able to use a filter like "*.*" but for example if you wanted all xml and txt files you could do {".xml", ".txt"}

```
FileSystemWatcher objWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(); 
objWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged); 

string[] filters = new string[] { "test", "blah", ".exe"}; //this needs to be a member of the class so it can be accessed from the Changed event

private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (filters.Any(e.FullPath).Contains))
    {     
        string strFileExt = getFileExt(e.FullPath); 
    }
}
```

This should give you a basic idea of how you might do it.

Comment: Thank you all, I wish there was an option to mark more than one as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileSystemWatcher` component provides a `Path` and `Filter` property to identify the files that you want to watch. You can use wildcards in the `Filter` property to watch multiple files, but beyond that there isn't any built-in functionality to watch an arbitrary set of files at once. From the [`Filter` property documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter(v=vs.110).aspx): Use of multiple filters such as "*.txt|*.doc" is not supported.

What you will probably need to do is create a distinct `FileSystemWatcher` for each of the items in your list.