# FileSystemWatcher - Filter to identify all files except those matching matching a string

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Is it possible to configure a FileSystemWatcher to identify all files, except files with the name containing a string of text?

For example, I want a FileSystemWatcher to identify all files, *except* `.xml` files. Can this be done?

I currently have:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher()
{
    Filter = "*" // identifies all files
};

watcher.Created += OnChanged;

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.ToLower().EndsWith(".xml"))
    {
        return;
    }
    // otherwise, do some stuff
}
```

This gets the job done, but I would rather not trigger the event when a `.xml` is found, if possible.

Comment: From other similar questions,  (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965184/how-to-set-filter-for-filesystemwatcher-for-multiple-file-types)), I dont think this is possible, but I'll this question here to see if anyone knows otherwise.

Comment: Think you are looking for the [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.filter?view=netframework-4.8) property.

Comment: There isn't one. The Filter is used to include files. Btw, use [Path.GetExtension()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension) to extract the file extension. Btw2, you should not manage anything in the event handler. Pass the file name to a *manager class* that handles the file processing (enqueues/dequeues the jobs and then pass them to the actual handler, consider it a pre-processor). It will take care of discarding what's in the black list.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use a pattern in the filenames to watch.

`*files*.*` to match all files containing the string `files`