# FileSystemWatcher on separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, .net-core, filesystemwatcher

I have to create script which will push some files into provided location and grab the output generated by other script.

1. Copy files to location.
2. Other script will grab the files and process them.
3. Wait for all results.
4. Get data from files, remove files.
5. Repeat steps for next stack of files.

On my PC everything works fine but when I run my script on the machine where Windows Server 2016 is running some error pop-up:
[image]

So I created a SystemWatcher which is monitoring a provided location

```
    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    private void RunWatcher(string location)
    {
        // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
        {
            watcher.Path = location;

            // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
            // the renaming of files or directories.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
                                | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                                | NotifyFilters.FileName
                                | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            watcher.Filter = "*";

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Created += OnCreate;

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // quit the program.
            while (!endWatcher);
        }
    }
    private void OnCreate(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    { 
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
        if (extensionWatch.Contains(fileExtension))
        {
            SaveFileData(fileExtension, e.FullPath);
        }
    }
```

The watcher is created on separate thread. Then a "while" loop inside the "for" is checking if all files has been created or if the "Abandon time" has been exceeded.

```
    private void PushFiles(string destinationPath, int timeAbandon, BackgroundWorker worker)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Before start watcher");
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            RunWatcher(destinationPath);
        });    
        Console.WriteLine("After start watcher");
        timeAbandon *= 60; // to sec
        
        for (int i = 0; i < fileCollect.Count; i++)
        {
            double timeDiff;
            start = DateTime.UtcNow;
            currentListIdx = i;
            CopyPtx(fileCollect[i], destinationPath);
            while (!CheckIfDone(i))
            {
                timeDiff = (DateTime.UtcNow - start).TotalSeconds;
                if (timeDiff > timeAbandon)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for results...");
            }
            CopyAndRemoveFiles(fileCollect[i], destinationPath);
            worker.ReportProgress(1);
        }
        endWatcher = true;
    }

    private bool CheckIfDone(int stackId)
    {
        bool isDone = true;
        foreach (var file in fileCollect[stackId])
        {
            if (file["finished"] == "false")
            {
                isDone = false;
            }
        }
        if (isDone)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I did have a look on Just-In-Time settings and "Managed, Native, Script" are selected. Also I use .net Core as I can't install any dependencies on the server machine.

To run the script on the server I do publish the script first with a following settings:
[image]
I tried to change the Configuration setting to "Debug|AnyCPU" but it didn't help.

Can anyone help me to get more information about the error? Or possible solution to my problem?

Comment: Did you try to attach a debugger to the program? Instead, add logging to investigate the actual error. I _bet_ it's an access denied issue.

Comment: Unrelated: `string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);  if (extensionWatch.Contains(fileExtension))` - why not set the filter correctly, instead?

Comment: `while (!endWatcher);` - **why??** No... You absolutely do not need this!

Comment: I think you really should try a deep dive into [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library).

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for your comments, I found a problem and it's related to one of my functions inside function SaveFileData so I don't think that this is related to the threads (I will post answer later). About filters. I need multiple filters and the answer for [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965184/how-to-set-filter-for-filesystemwatcher-for-multiple-file-types) didn't work form me.  Without    while (!endWatcher); loop my watcher is terminated even before my script copy the files.

Comment: _" Without while (!endWatcher); loop my watcher is terminated even before my script copy the files."_ - that's because you `use` it. Which you shouldn't. Create it and keep it until you exit your program without `use` and spin.

Answer (score 0):

There was en error in function `SaveFileData(fileExtension, e.FullPath);`. The error appeard because I was trying to read file before saving into file was finished. So The title of this post is not correct.

To solve the problem with access to file I used a following code.

```
    protected virtual bool IgnoreErrorMsg(FileInfo file, string ignoreMsg)
    {
        bool isAccess = false;

        while (!isAccess)
        {
            try
            {
                using (FileStream stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                {
                    //if file can be read, then read it
                    if (stream.CanRead)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
                        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        string errorString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        if (errorString.Contains(ignoreMsg))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        // access has been granted so loop can be exit
                        isAccess = true;
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                //the loop will continue as long as "cannot access" error appear
                isAccess = false;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        //if return false, then script will wait for optimisation unitil AbandonTime
        return false;
    }
```

In that case the title of the post is not correct because it's not related to multithreading.